# How to Test IAM Roles for an App Registration

Tags: azure, azure-rbac, azure-app-registration

I'm troubleshooting an issue where an app registration is unable to query the subscriptions within an Azure tenant, despite a role assignment granting it access at the tenant root group level. Wondering if there's a straightforward method to run the relevant command, either through CLI or the web interface, to validate this behavior.

Specific test command is: az account management-group list

But I don't see any way to invoke that as a particular user or app, and I already know my own user account has the right permissions, and can run that command. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can log in as the service principal, is this what you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli-service-principal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, fetch your service principal's `ObjectID` that can be found in **Enterprise Applications** like this:

[image]

To check the **IAM roles** assigned for that app registration, you can make use of below CLI Command by passing above `ObjectID` like this:

```bash
principalId="SPObjectID"
az role assignment list --all --query "[?principalId=='$principalId'].{RoleName:roleDefinitionName,Scope:scope, PrincipalID:principalId, PrincipalName:'$(az ad sp show --id $principalId --query displayName -o tsv)'}" --output table
```

**Response:**

[image]

As *@KonTheCat* suggested, you can login as **service principal** and connect to Azure by running below CLI command:

```bash
az login --service-principal -u "appID" -p "client_secret" --tenant "tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below CLI command now, I got the **response** with list of subscriptions successfully like this:

```
az account subscription list
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: That works, thank you! Had to add one more permission, 'Microsoft.Management/register/action' on the app's subscription to be able to run the specific management group command.